# Angular 5 routing from database driven menu with classic asp needing to route to specific page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-routing, angular-router

I have data provided to me from web api looking at a database , so it is all dynamically driven, however I want to be able to read a specific classic asp page and then redirect to specific route.

**Example URL**

```
http://localhost:4200/iCIS/Criminal/ARSCodeLookup.asp%3FUserID%3D61525%26AppID%3D15%26AppGroupID%3D116%26SelectedCaseID%3D0%26SelectedRoleID%3D0
```

So If it finds   `ARSCodeLookup.asp`  then i want to route to

```
http://localhost:4200/inquiry?UserID=61644&AppID=15&AppGroupID=118&SelectedCaseID=0&SelectedRoleID=0&TranTime=12%2F11%2F2017%2010:51:15%20AM&LoginKey=202088840
```

In my `app.routes.module.ts`  I have

```
 { path: 'inquiry', component: InquiryComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Is this possible and how do i do this?

Comment: I'm not clear on the *this* you are referring to in "how do I do this". Do you need information on how to read the query parameters from the route? Or something else?

Comment: Yes,   I have a new angular site in which the database driven menu provides me with .asp page etc.. and I need to read and parse the url and route accordingly    thx

Comment: @DeborahK   -- any resources  ?   All I see are params in google searches    thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear on the question you are asking ... but if you simply need to know how to read the parameters from a route using the query parameter syntax, then the syntax would be something like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    let userId = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('UserID');
    let appId = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('AppID');
    // ...
}
```

Here is more information that may help:

[image]

Comment: Every .ts page has no issues hitting its own `ngOnInit()`  except for this app.routes.module.ts    It doesn't want to , extremely odd.

Comment: app.routes.module is not a component and so should have no ngOnInit method in it. Move the code to a component ... not a module.